# How do i got about creating a method that can check if there is enough funds in the account to allow the withdrawal or insufficient funds

Tags: java

here is what i have so far.
How do i got about Adding a method to make a withdrawal, which receives the withdrawal amount as a parameter. i want this method to also check that there is sufficient funds in the account to allow the withdrawal. If there are insufficient funds, then the method should display the message “Insufficient funds for this withdrawal”.

```
public class CurrentAccount {
int accountNumber;
float balance;

//Constructor 
public CurrentAccount(int accountNumber, float balance) {
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    this.balance = balance;

}

//Getters
public int getAccountNumber() {
    return this.accountNumber;
}

public float getBalance() {
    return this.balance;
}

//Setters
public void setAccountNumber(int accountNumber) {
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
}

public void setBalance(float balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

public float lodgement(float num1){
    float lodge = num1;
    return lodge;
}

public float withdrawel(float num2) {
    float with = num2;
    return with;
}
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You've already got the `withdrawl` method:

`public float withdrawel(float num2)`

You've also got access to all the information to implement the calculation:

```
public float withdrawel(float num2) {
    float with = num2;
    if (this.balance < with){
        System.out.println( "Insufficient funds ( " 
            + this.balance + ") for this withdrawal " + with);
    }
    else {
        this.balance -= with;
    }
    return this.balance;
}
```

Using this method you can now try to withdrawl different amounts from the account:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    int acctnum = 1971;
    float acctbal = (float) 198.45;
    float withdrawl1 = (float) 500.50;  # should throw Insufficient Funds message 
    float withdrawl2 = (float) 20.50;   # should successfully withdrawl

    CurrentAccount ca = new CurrentAccount(acctnum, acctbal);

    System.out.println("Account " + acctnum + ": " + ca.getBalance());
    ca.withdrawel(withdrawl1);
    System.out.println("End Balance: " + ca.getBalance());
    ca.withdrawel(withdrawl2);
    System.out.println("End Balance: " + ca.getBalance());
}
```

Demo:

```
Account 1971: 198.45
Insufficient funds ( 198.45) for this withdrawal 500.5
End Balance: 198.45
End Balance: 177.95
```

Comment: Hopefully you'll be there for the test. Instead of doing their homework for them, maybe it would be more beneficial/educational to provide guidance, instead of doing it for them?